# Readgssi Package, how i can get a variable from a diffrent file

Tags: python, get, header

I'm trying to understand the readgssi package : https://readgssi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

so if you want to read a DZT file you need to type this commande :

```
hdr, arrs, gps = readgssi.readgssi(infile='COMMON__030.DZT', verbose=True)
```

after that you get a couple of informations like :

```
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - traces per second:  110.0
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - traces per meter:   300.0
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - epsr:               1.0
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - speed of wave:      3.00E+08 m/sec (99.99% of vacuum)
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - time range (TWTT):  10.0 ns
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - sampling depth:     1.7 m
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - "rhf_top":          -0.2 m
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - "rhf_depth":        1.5 m
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - offset to data:     1024 bytes
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - traces:             3608
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - seconds:            32.80000000
2021-04-23 10:45:41 - array dimensions:   256 x 3608
```

my question is how i can acces to this informations, for exemple i want to get time range as a variable and use it in some plotting

Thank you